# Obtener dato desde Ajax y almacenarlo en variable PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables

antes que nada aclaro que son mis primeros pasos en PHP.
Y me he encontrado con una dificultad:
He creado un archivo.php, el cual a través de javascript recibe un dato mediante Ajax. Esto funciona sin problemas.
Lo que necesito y no se como hacer, es que cuando llegue el dato por Ajax, ese dato se pase a una variable PHP y se ejecuten varias funciones PHP.

Intenté poniendo código PHP en el success de Ajax, pero no funciona.

Alguna sugerencia de como realizar esto?
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Tienes que hacer otra peticion ajax en el success a una url nueva donde se va ejecutar el código que necesitas.

Comment: Puedes poner el código para ayudarte.

Comment: Hola!, podrias dejarnos mas informacion para la comunidad como compartir codigo?. Aca te dejo una guia -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente lo que estas preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías al menos poner tu codigo ajax para darte una mejor respuesta.

Pero bueno, suponiendo que tu ajax está enviando bien los datos al archivo .php, para recibirlos puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

Si has colocado la configuración de ajax por GET.

```
<?php
$varAjax = $_GET['parametroUrl'];
if(isset($varAjax)){
    // $varAjax tendrá los datos que enviaste por GET (mediante la URL)
}
?>
```

Si lo has hecho de manera POST.

```
<?Php
$varAjax = $_POST['variableAjax'];
if(isset($varAjax)){
    //$varAjax tendra el valor de lo que enviaste por ajax desde el js
}
?>
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un problema al entender que es AJAX, como funciona tu código javascript y tu código PHP.

Tu código javascript se ejecuta en el cliente y el código PHP se ejecuta en servidor, cuando en el cliente escriben en la dirección URL  http://tuserver.com/archivo.php, el archivo.php se ejecuta en el servidor tuserver.com con todas las instrucciones php escritas, y cuando llega al cliente, lo que llega es tipicamente codigo html que es interpretado por el cliente donde puede haber además de HTML, código javascript que es ejecutado por el navegador.

Ajax lo que intenta hacer es que ya enviado un texto o html con código javascript, vuelva a pedir al servidor otra URL sin recargar todo el contenido, ni cambiar la dirección web en el navegador, esto para llenar información en el HTML o para cambiar un pedazo del mismo HTML o más, entonces cuando usas Ajax pides una nueva URL, que puede ser http://tudominio.com/archivo2.php al servidor, por lo que en tu servidor tendrías que escribir otro archivo en tu htdocs con nombre archivo2.php y ahí si volverías a ejecutar de nuevo código PHP.

Answer (score -1):

quieres una variable en tu php en donde se almacenen datos y poder acceder a ella en cualquier petición que hagas en ajax.
puedes optar por variables de session.
de esta forma puedes empezar a utilizar las variables

Inicias la session
session_start();

crear una varibles
$_SESSION['tu_variable'] = '1';

acceder al valor de las variables
echo $_SESSION['tu_variable'];
o de esta otra forma
$variable=$_SESSION['tu_variable'];

aquí puedes encontrar mas información

https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/how-to-use-sessions-and-session-variables-in-php--cms-31839

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.